# How do I get a bold version of a custom font?

Tags: html, css

I have used the CSS command

```
@font-face { font-family: myFont; src: url('MyFont.otf'); }
```

to install my own font on a HTML site.

Now, when I use the `<strong>` tag, I don't see a bold version of it. How do I do to make this work?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create link on MyFontBold.otf . Italic, bold, medium, semibold, thin it's different files of font. Example

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v5/LKf8nhXsWg5ybwEGXk8UBQ.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('PT Sans Bold'), local('PTSans-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v5/0XxGQsSc1g4rdRdjJKZrNBsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('PT Sans Italic'), local('PTSans-Italic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v5/PIPMHY90P7jtyjpXuZ2cLD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('PT Sans Bold Italic'), local('PTSans-BoldItalic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v5/lILlYDvubYemzYzN7GbLkHhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
```

After this code you can use bold, italic and outher property of font

Comment: I guess it should work without additional font weights, see [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBxlL).

Comment: Do I have to have a bold version of the font? Isn't possible to fake it using the weight property?

Comment: Some browsers can do this, but it is not cross-browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

you can use font-weight..

```
@font-face {
font-family: "xyz";
src: url("xyz.ttf");
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```

Comment: font weight is not working for me. Do I have to have a bold version of the font or will it work with any font.

Comment: actually the browser will try to fake the bold and italic styles if it can’t find them

Answer (score 0):

use `<b> bold </b>` tag

Comment: "Do not confuse the <b> element with the <strong>, <em>, or <mark> elements. The <strong> element represents text of certain importance, <em> puts some emphasis on the text and the <mark> element represents text of certain relevance. The <b> element doesn't convey such special semantic information; use it only when no others fit." in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b